# Is incrementing a number with an UPDATE statement reliable on different sessions?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, isolation-level

Using the default isolation level:  READ COMMITTED, would the following proc be guaranteed to return a different number for each session? Basically, is it possible for one session to execute this proc at the same time as another session, and return the same value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNextVersion(@id uniqueidentifier)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MySequenceTable
        SET mySequenceField = mySequenceField + 1 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.mySequenceField
    where IdField = @id
END
GO
```

**Note:** We cannot use the new sequence object in SQL Server 2012, nor is this a scenario where an identity column would work.

Comment: No. That won't work, you will have to use an exclusive table lock to serialize access to the values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your input, but that really seems like using a sledgehammer to drive a tack into a cork board.  I'm no expert on sql server locking strategies (which is why i'm asking this question), but it seems to me like there must be an isolation level setting that would ensure the database engine handles this internally.  Do you know of any documentation that supports what you are saying?

Comment: Ah, you are right. I wasn't thinking about the locking of the row that happens (I guess you are aware that this is going to make your application really slow). But rollbacks will be a problem. If the caller rolls back the transaction but still uses the supplied value the next transaction will use the same value.

Comment: We have considered the performance implications, but since this is an isolated procedure (it is the only thing that will run in the transaction)...we think it will not be a problem.  We just want to ensure that two consumers will never receive the same value.  Thank you for the heads up on rollbacks, we will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you get and set the value in one statement without using the output clause it will be unique regardless of isolation level (assuming no error.)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNextVersion
@id uniqueidentifier,
@mySequenceField int output
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE MySequenceTable
SET @mySequenceField = mySequenceField,  mySequenceField + 1 
where IdField = @id
END
GO
```

Note that the variable will update first so the table is left with the next sequence value already incremented.

Also why do you have an id in the where clause? Wouldnt this work fine if MySequenceTable had only one row?

Comment: Does this mean the "output" clause is *not* atomic?

Comment: not sure, it might well be but i know that using a variable update is guaranteed as i have tested it. Also a bit more readable i think...

Comment: The IdField is in the where clause because MySequenceTable will have any number of rows.  The sequence field is actually a version number, and we need to ensure that multiple concurrent users never receive the same version number when they make changes.

Comment: well my answer will do that for you.